# How to remove certain trailing characters in PHP?

Tags: php, parsing, latex

I'm trying to make a LaTeX parser in PHP, and I want to remove certain trailing new lines (`\\` signs).

But the problem is, I only want to remove the new line (the double backslash) if it's before everything else.

Like, I want to remove the first `\\` in the following example:

```
\\3+6=9
```

But not this `\\`:

```
3+\\6=9
```

How can I do this with PHP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `trim`

```
$arr = trim('your_string','\\');
```

working example http://codepad.viper-7.com/OaYxWG

Answer (score 1):

Use trim in php

```
i.e.,

trim("string","\\");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following

```
$a = "\\aaaaa";

if (substr($a, 0, 1) === '\\') { 
    echo trim($a,'\\');     
 }
```

It will echo out "aaaaa". Hope this helps